# converting list of type Integer to list of type Int

Tags: haskell

i'm trying to convert this list [1..20] from [Integer] to [Int]

```
map fromInteger [1..20]
```

however this still gives me a list of Integers

This on its own converts 2 which is Integer type to Int
    fromInteger 2 :: Int

What's wrong

Comment: `map fromInteger [1..20]` actually works fine, but you may be bitten by type defaulting and the monomorphism restriction, which sends it right back to `[Integer]` if you are not careful to specify which type you actually want! So add a type annotation: `map fromInteger [1..20] :: [Int]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Haskell, values can – just like functions – be polymorphic.

This idea is familiar to most programmers for the numerical *operators*: nobody finds it strange that `5 + 6` works, yielding and integer, just as fine as `3.14159 + 2.71828` works yielding a float. But in languages like C this is done pretty much ad-hoc, just because this special case is so handy. This brings a lot of problems with it, in particular when you write things like `1/12`, which will carry out the `/` as integer-division, resulting in `0`. Clearly not the intended thing when ou use it in something like

```c
for (double hourWay = 0; hourWay<1; hourWay += 1/12)
  double theta = hourWay * 2 * pi;
  ...
```

So programmers have to resort to ugly hacks like writing out the fraction in decimal, or explicitly making one of the numbers float (`1.0 / 12.0`, urgh!).

Haskell does this automatically for us: when it sees the result will be a double (that's explicitly written out in `hourWay`s declaration) it makes no sense to start that calculation with integers, so it interprets `1` and `12` as floating-point right away. No problem with that since the integers certainly form a subset of the reals<sup>1</sup>. You can directly access this functionality by giving explicit type signatures:

> Prelude> 4 :: Int
>   4
>   Prelude> 4 :: Double
>   4.0

Note that `:: Double` does not *convert* the number. `4` by itself does not have any particular type at all, it's polymorphic: whatever number type you want, `4` is a valid description; this is expressed in the type system by the signature

> Prelude> :t 4
>   4 :: Num a => a

And in particular, this means

> Prelude> :t [1..20]
>   [1..20] :: (Num t, Enum t) => [t]

is also polymorphic, which allows you to write

> Prelude> [1..20] :: [Int]
>   [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
>   Prelude> [1..20] :: [Double]
>   [1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0,7.0,8.0,9.0,10.0,11.0,12.0,13.0,14.0,15.0,16.0,17.0,18.0,19.0,20.0]

Only when you don't give any signature, ghci will *default* to the "safest bet", which is `Integer`.

So in the case of `[1..20]` you don't need `fromInteger` at all. You would need it though if some elements weren't given directly as literals, but external constants / arguments of fixed type `Integer`.

> Prelude> let x = 13 :: Integer
>   Prelude> :t [1..12]++[x]++[14..20]
>   [1..12]++[x]++[14..20] :: [Integer]
>   Prelude> map fromInteger ([1..12]++[x]++[14..20]) :: [Int]
>   [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]

This works again with any numerical result type you request, because although `x` prevents `[1..12]++[x]++[14..20]` from being polymorphic, `fromInteger` re-introduces that.

> Prelude> :t map fromInteger ([1..12]++[x]++[14..20]) :: [Int]
>   map fromInteger ([1..12]++[x]++[14..20]) :: Num b => [b]

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>Which doesn't actually mean `Double` forms a subtype of `Integer` or even `Int`... it doesn't; but this becomes a problem only for big numbers.</sub>

Comment: THANKS so much for the extremely clear explaination especially for introducing polymorphic values!